# Lenovo Windows 10 laptop turn off content aware brightness

Tags: windows-10, laptop, lenovo-laptop

I have just purchased a Lenovo V15 ADA laptop and the brightness keeps dimming when I switch to look at my desktop (when no windows are open). If I plug my charging cable in whilst on the desktop it will go bright again. This must be a power saving thing but I cannot find the option to turn it off anywhere, I've set battery power mode to best performance and there was no change.

Comment: I don't remember exact name and location of this feature, but look for _adaptive contrast_ or _adaptive brightness_ in the Intel Graphics control panel.

Comment: I don't have intel graphics I have AMD Ryzen 5, where should I look?

Comment: I found it when I looked for Radeon in my start menu thank-you for the point in the right direction

Answer (score 1):

Solved! I fixed it by Radeon settings lite in my start menu and turning off the setting "vari-bright" in the display tab.

I have no idea why they have to make these things so difficult, and even further have no idea why it's on by default.

Comment: __I have no idea why they have to make these things so difficult__ Welcome to the world of Microsoft Windows... ;-)